# Do stretching or do stretches

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Do stretching or do stretches,which ones are correct and more commen? If both are right, where and when should I use them?

Comment: Spelling: "common"

Comment: Please provide the context. What do you intend to say using these words? Do you have full sentences in mind?

Answer (score 2):

"Stretching", or "to stretch" is the normal expression and can be used in most situations. It is better to use the verb "stretch" than to force the gerund "do stretching"

> Stretching is important before running
>
> You should stretch before exercise. Stretch each muscle group in turn.

Using the noun "stretch" suggests a particular form or way of stretching.

> The "sideways arch" is a useful stretch for gymnasts

So saying "do stretches" suggests "do a particular sequence of stretches"

> {Coach} Girls! Have you all done your stretches?  Nobody plays football until everybody has finished stretching.